# Down sides of abusing O(1) lookup of a hash table?

Tags: c++, hashtable

Hash tables are very common data structures used for coding problems presented in competitive programming/interviews.

Hash tables take key value pairs so that you can lookup a key and get the value. However, I often find myself needing the `O(1)` lookup of a key and not really caring about the value.

**For example:**

If I need to know if some `strings` have been used previously, I might plug them into a hash table with `key: string`, `value: bool` where the value of the bool is always true.

What are the down sides of doing something like this? Are there other data structures that give O(1) lookup that don't need a key value pair?

Comment: There are many different kinds oh hash tables, all with their own performance characteristics.  Is there a particular type you are interested in?  For instance, a `std::unordered_map` basically has to b implemented as an array of linked lists, and I'm sure you know the performance penalty there is to traverse a list.

Comment: `unordered_set` is a generalization of a `<type, bool>` hash table with O(1) lookup/insert.  There's no real downside of using it.  As with any collection class in C++, YMMV on performance with regards to implementation and memory allocation overhead.

Comment: @selbie wasn't aware of this, ty

Comment: All hash table implementations have poor worst-case performance.  A lot depends on how well spread out your hash values are.

Comment: You could also try other data sets with `O(logn)` for small inputs the `c` constant might be smaller and give better performance. Try it out.

Comment: It's average case complexity is `order(1)` and worst case complexity is `O(N)`.

Comment: Hash tables do need more RAM than lists or trees.  It is a bit of a RAM for speed trade off, again unless you have a perfect hash.  You will also need to do the hash and a string compare per string in a "bucket" - again unless your hash is perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a data structure the way it's intended to be used. And then you can profile your code to see if the performance is adequate. If it isn't, then optimize bottlenecks.

Having said that, a better data structure to check if a string has already been used would be [std::unordered_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) or [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). Your use case is a typical use case for a set data structure. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)):

> In computer science, a set is an abstract data type that can store
> unique values, without any particular order. It is a computer
> implementation of the mathematical concept of a finite set. Unlike
> most other collection types, rather than retrieving a specific element
> from a set, one typically tests a value for membership in a set.

Answer (score 3):

If the sole purpose of this container to test whether a string has already been used, then [unordered_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) (collection of unique keys, hashed by keys) would do the trick.

> Unordered set is an associative container that contains a set of
> unique objects of type Key. Search, insertion, and removal have
> average constant-time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a perfect hash algorithm you will have collisions. At that point you have to look at your actual hash table implementation. Which each has their advantages and disadvantages, currently all `std::unordered_map` (and `std::unordered_set`?) are implemented as buckets with linked lists, which then makes your O(1) to a worst case of O(N).
The average is still O(1), so if your system is not time critical and you use a good hashing, as of a few years ago the hash for strings used some academically accepted good algorithm, then use a hash set. If you on the other hand in no way can accept a worst case O(N) lookup use `std::map` or `std::set`.

- Note 1: all hash tables has an Achilles heel that makes them worst case O(N), unless your buckets are implemented as a balanced tree.
- Note 2: Perfect hashing is without collisions.
- Note 3: there is some literature that can tell how to make a perfect hash from known data, haven't seen any yet for perfect hashes for unknown data.
- Note 4: if you find the latter then you might be able to prove P = NP.